# Como desenhar em um JDialog

Tags: java, swing

Olá. tenho uma janela em JDialog, onde coloco vários componentes, o que fica assim:

[image: sem nada]

E precisava fazer algo mais ou menos assim:

[image: com o bagui]

como essa tela é muito grande, eu vou postar apenas parte do código dela:

```
JPanel pnHe = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel pnHeC1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
JPanel pnHeC1Aux = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 1));
JPanel pnHeC1L1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
JPanel pnHeC1L2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
JPanel pnHeC1L3 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
JPanel pnHeC1L4 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
JPanel pnHeC1L5 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
JPanel pnHeC1L6 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
JPanel pnHeC1L7 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
JPanel pnHeC1L8 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
JPanel pnHeSem = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
JPanel pnHeSemAux = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 1));
JPanel pnHeSemSeg = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
JPanel pnHeSemTer = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
JPanel pnHeSemQua = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
JPanel pnHeSemQui = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
JPanel pnHeSemSex = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
JPanel pnHeSemSab = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
JPanel pnHeSemDom = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
JPanel pnHeSemFer = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));

JCheckBox chHeSeg = new JCheckBox("Seg ");
JCheckBox chHeTer = new JCheckBox("Ter  ");
JCheckBox chHeQua = new JCheckBox("Qua ");
JCheckBox chHeQui = new JCheckBox("Qui  ");
JCheckBox chHeSex = new JCheckBox("Sex ");
JCheckBox chHeSab = new JCheckBox("Sab ");
JCheckBox chHeDom = new JCheckBox("Dom");
JCheckBox chHeFer = new JCheckBox("Fer  ");

JCheckBox chHeSegAp = new JCheckBox("Apura Agrupado");
JCheckBox chHeTerAp = new JCheckBox("Apura Agrupado");
JCheckBox chHeQuaAp = new JCheckBox("Apura Agrupado");
JCheckBox chHeQuiAp = new JCheckBox("Apura Agrupado");
JCheckBox chHeSexAp = new JCheckBox("Apura Agrupado");
JCheckBox chHeSabAp = new JCheckBox("Apura Agrupado");
JCheckBox chHeDomAp = new JCheckBox("Apura Agrupado");
JCheckBox chHeFerAp = new JCheckBox("Apura Agrupado");

JTextField tfHeSeg = new JTextField(4);
JTextField tfHeTer = new JTextField(4);
JTextField tfHeQua = new JTextField(4);
JTextField tfHeQui = new JTextField(4);
JTextField tfHeSex = new JTextField(4);
JTextField tfHeSab = new JTextField(4);
JTextField tfHeDom = new JTextField(4);
JTextField tfHeFer = new JTextField(4);

JCheckBox chHeDiario = new JCheckBox("Apura excedente Diário");
JCheckBox chHeSemana = new JCheckBox("Apura excedente Semanal");
JCheckBox chHeDsr = new JCheckBox("Apura excedente DSR (Domingos/Feriados)");
JCheckBox chHeDiuNot = new JCheckBox("Apura Diurno/Noturno separadamente");
JCheckBox chHeDiaSem = new JCheckBox("Apura excedente Diário/Semanal");
JCheckBox chHeNotSep = new JCheckBox("Apura excedente das \"horas noturnas acrescidas\" separadamente");
JCheckBox chHeEncerr = new JCheckBox("Apura excedente jornada Noturna até o encerramento do cartão");
JCheckBox chHeDupTri = new JCheckBox("Horas extras duplas/triplas");
```

Construção:

```
    pnHeC1L1.add(chHeDiario);
    pnHeC1L2.add(chHeSemana);
    pnHeC1L3.add(chHeDiaSem);
    pnHeC1L4.add(chHeDiuNot);
    pnHeC1L5.add(chHeDsr);
    pnHeC1L6.add(chHeNotSep);
    pnHeC1L7.add(chHeEncerr);
    pnHeC1L8.add(chHeDupTri);
    pnHeC1L8.add(tfHeFaixa1);
    pnHeC1L8.add(tfHeFaixa2);

    tfHeFaixa1.setEnabled(false);
    tfHeFaixa2.setEnabled(false);

    pnHeSemSeg.add(chHeSeg);
    chHeSeg.setSelected(true);
    pnHeSemSeg.add(tfHeSeg);
    pnHeSemSeg.add(chHeSegAp);

    pnHeSemTer.add(chHeTer);
    chHeTer.setSelected(true);
    pnHeSemTer.add(tfHeTer);
    pnHeSemTer.add(chHeTerAp);

    pnHeSemQua.add(chHeQua);
    chHeQua.setSelected(true);
    pnHeSemQua.add(tfHeQua);
    pnHeSemQua.add(chHeQuaAp);

    pnHeSemQui.add(chHeQui);
    chHeQui.setSelected(true);
    pnHeSemQui.add(tfHeQui);
    pnHeSemQui.add(chHeQuiAp);

    pnHeSemSex.add(chHeSex);
    chHeSex.setSelected(true);
    pnHeSemSex.add(tfHeSex);
    pnHeSemSex.add(chHeSexAp);

    pnHeSemSab.add(chHeSab);
    chHeSab.setSelected(true);
    pnHeSemSab.add(tfHeSab);
    pnHeSemSab.add(chHeSabAp);

    pnHeSemDom.add(chHeDom);
    chHeDom.setSelected(true);
    pnHeSemDom.add(tfHeDom);
    pnHeSemDom.add(chHeDomAp);

    pnHeSemFer.add(chHeFer);
    chHeFer.setSelected(true);
    pnHeSemFer.add(tfHeFer);
    pnHeSemFer.add(chHeFerAp);

    pnHeSemAux.add(pnHeSemDom);
    pnHeSemAux.add(pnHeSemSeg);
    pnHeSemAux.add(pnHeSemTer);
    pnHeSemAux.add(pnHeSemQua);
    pnHeSemAux.add(pnHeSemQui);
    pnHeSemAux.add(pnHeSemSex);
    pnHeSemAux.add(pnHeSemSab);
    pnHeSemAux.add(pnHeSemFer);
    pnHeSem.add(pnHeSemAux);
    pnHeSemAux.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());

    pnHeC1Aux.add(pnHeC1L1);
    pnHeC1Aux.add(pnHeC1L2);
    pnHeC1Aux.add(pnHeC1L3);
    pnHeC1Aux.add(pnHeC1L4);
    pnHeC1Aux.add(pnHeC1L5);
    pnHeC1Aux.add(pnHeC1L6);
    pnHeC1Aux.add(pnHeC1L7);
    pnHeC1Aux.add(pnHeC1L8);
    pnHeC1.add(pnHeC1Aux);

    pnHe.add(pnHeC1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pnHe.add(pnHeSem, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para colocar aquela chave ali, seguido das 3 opções, sei que é algo básico, mas não consegui pensar em outra solução sem usar o setBounds ou usar imagens. Mas pode ser que tenha algo que faça eu "desenhar" no JPanel, algo que faça a estilização igual à borda onde tem os dias da semana, mas em formato de chave.

Comment: Coloque o JLabel com uma imagem de `}` naquele local, simples. :)

Comment: acontece que é pra cobrir 2 linhas, com o mesmo `}` por isso postei a pergunta, as 2 linhas são representadas por 2 JPanels, por uma questão de organização, além disso, estou achando um pouco complicado colocar as outras 3 opções logo na frente da chave usando os layouts que eu usei

Comment: Eu havia entendido isso mesmo, e dá pra fazer com uma imagem e com JLabel, basta posicionar ele naquele espaço, com altura igual a dos dois paineis e adicionar uma imagem de mesma altura.

Comment: mas um dos paineis não vai "encobrir" a imagem? mesmo não tendo nada na frente?

Comment: Depende, adicione o código da sua tela(se for grande demais pra pergunta, pode ser em site externo como pastebin), para que seja possivel reproduzir ela para testes,

Comment: http://pastebin.com/D7z6wQDC dê uma olhada, sei que tem muita coisa mal feita, e muita coisa "a toa" mas acho que dá para dar uma olhada, é só tirar o action dos botões que o resto funciona

Comment: Não parece estar completo. Nem está em uma classe que estenda JFrame.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42500/discussion-between-thomas-braz-pinto-and-diegofm).

Comment: O tamanho da chave é dinâmico ou sempre será fixo?